# DotNetCore Authorization Policy not being picked up in debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-authorization, .net-core

I have an auth policy configured in startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
        {
            auth.AddPolicy("Bearer", policy => policy
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build());

        });
```

and I am using this in an attribute on an api controller:

`[Authorize("Bearer")]`

When I run the debugger in VS code, I get an exception :
`fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HL14EICAK26S": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: The AuthorizationPolicy named: 'Bearer' was not found.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationPolicy.<CombineAsync>d__9.MoveNext()`

When I run the program via `dotnet  run`, I don't get this exception and it's able to pick up on the authorization attribute.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaned, restored and rebuilt the project ... and it magically worked again....

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the following to get everything to work in my project. Here is Startup.cs

```
//Authentication
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddScheme<AuthOptions1, AuthenticationHandler1>("Scheme1", opt => { })
    .AddScheme<AuthOptions2, AuthenticationHandler2>("Scheme2", opt => { });

//Authorization
services.AddAuthorization(opt =>
{
    opt.AddPolicy("Policy1", policy =>
    {
        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("Scheme1");
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
    opt.AddPolicy("Policy2", policy =>
    {
        policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes("Scheme2");
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
});
```

And then in my controllers I added this:

```
[Authorize("Policy1")]
```